# Get coordinates from pyzbar decode

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the coordinates from a scanned QR-code using the pyzbar module. If I use the following code below to do this:

```
    test = decode(img)
    print(test)
```

I get the following result:

[Decoded(data=b'Part4', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=172, top=332, width=75, height=76))]

The problem however, is that I do not know how to just extract the rect part of this string. I'm using spyder, and if I go to the variable explorer to try and see how the variable is built-up, I get the following error:

AttributeError("Can't get attribute 'Rect' on ",)

Anyone know what could be it?

Comment: Please try to come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/blob/8e3e87da17ddd794842b2fcbbe0dd86c692d7511/pyzbar/pyzbar.py#L26), `Decoded` is a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). So your `test` is a list of namedtuples. You can get the rect of the first result like this:

```
rect = test[0].rect
```

Comment: Cheers, that works perfectly and thanks for adding a documentation link!

Answer (score 0):

there is another way that helps. 
you can change the data to Numpy array and use it with OpenCV and other libs will be easier. 
Exp:(import OpenCV, Numpy libs)

```
points = np.array(decoded_objects_by_pyzbar[0].polygon, np.int32)
cv.polylines(img,[points],True,(0,255,255),9)
cv.imshow("detected code", frame)
```